# как поделиться ссылкой на сайт и на конкретное место на странице этого сайта?

Tags: браузер

Как поделиться ссылкой на сайт и на конкретное место на странице этого сайта?
Не используя языков программирования.
Возможно есть плагин какой (Google chrome).
и вообще так возможно?

Например, есть [страница](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625528/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0). Как сделать, чтобы при переходе по ссылке страница открывалась на определенном месте? То есть, например, так:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а не в начале странице, как:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста подробнее как вы хотите делиться ссылкой. Лучше даже на примере.

Comment: _Как поделиться ссылкой на сайт_ Выделить весь адрес в строке адреса браузера. ПКМ - Копировать. В нужном месте ПКМ - Вставить. _на конкретное место на странице этого сайта_ Открыть исходный код страницы. Найти ближайшую к нужному месту метку. Если найдётся - добавить её к скопированному по методике выше адресу. Ну а если нет - то кому-то не повезло...

Comment: понятно @Akina.
В етом и бил вопрос можна ето зделать если нет метки

Comment: Если нет метки, то нет

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Спасибо